# No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options

Tags: metamask, react

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: No "from" address specified in neither the given options, nor the default options.
    at Object._executeMethod (index.js?2fac3b5:942)
    at CampaignNew._callee$ (new.js?76ccf38:18)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?60a82e3:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?60a82e3:296)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?60a82e3:114)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js?c130066:17)
    at asyncToGenerator.js?c130066:28
```

Code is:

```js
 onSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await instance.methods.createCampaign(this.state.amount).send({
        from: accounts[0]
    });
};
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Can you check with a JavaScript debugger or `console.log` that `accounts` and `accounts[0]` actually contain some value?

Comment: Most likely `web3.eth.getAccounts` returns an empty array, hence `accounts[0] === undefined`.